# Cordova command create apps by default do not include <access origin="*">?

Tags: android, node.js, cordova

In NodeJs v18 & Cordova@11.1 environment, after I created a project using "cordova create sampleapp com.sample.app SampleApp" command, "config.xml" file is not included , causing the program to be unable to access external web-sites.

I saw in the official cordova documentation guide(https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/guide/appdev/allowlist/index.html#network-request-allow-list) that it is automatically added by default, I wonder why it is not the default in the Cordova@11.1 version?

I tried to create the project in cordova@9 version, "config.xml" file and it will contain  by default, so I was wondering why  is not included by default in cordova@11.* version?